# How to print an array in descending order?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

Basically this is my code and it works fine. I just don't know how to print it in descending order. This code basically shows the odd numbers:1,3,5,7. I want it to be printed 7,5,3,1. I know I need use the sort function but I dont know how.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fillArray(int arr[], int &n);
void printArray(int arr[], int n);
void findSum(int arr[], int &n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    fillArray(arr,n);
    printArray(arr,n);
    findSum(arr,n);

    return 0;
}

void fillArray(int arr[], int &n)
{
    int j=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(j%2==1)
            arr[i]=j;
        else
            i--;
        j++;
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<", ";
    }
}

void findSum(int arr[], int &n)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reorder the array or are you trying to simply reverse the printing? If you want to reorder the array, you simply have to reverse it.

Comment: `std::sort(arr, arr + n, std::greater<>{});`.

Comment: Just loop from `rbegin()` to `rend()` when printing and you'll print from the end to the front (if you had used a proper container like `std::array` or `std::vector` rather than a old-school C-style array, that is).

Comment: you already have 'n' (max element in your array) use a loop to print each element starting in 'n - 1' until 0.

Comment: @Jarod42 he want only print elements from arrat, so he can't sort array, better is display from end to begin.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    cout << arr[i] << ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
void printArray(int *tab, int size)
{
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        std::cout << tab[i] << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    int tab[3] = { 1,2,3 };
    printArray(tab, 3);

}
```

You should begin from last element array, and decrement iterator (`i`) to `i == 0`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use a sort function. There is one included with the *algorithm* header.

```
#include <algorithm> // this goes at the top

void printArray(int arr[], int n)
{
  sort(arr, arr+n, [](int x, int y){return y<x;});

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
```

the `[](int x, int y){return y<x;}` part is just to make it descending. Normally it is y>x, at which point you can just omit the third parameter

Here is a repl:
https://repl.it/JQor/0

Comment: why you sort array in print method?

Comment: They said they wanted to use a sort function so I gave them an answer with a sort function. You give them the answer they want, not the answer you think is right. What if they were to read numbers from a file that was not sorted? Then the solution without a sort function would be incorrect. This way you can guarantee it will be in descending order